# What does numpy's * do to a variable?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm going through an online course, and don't understand the 4th line of this code:

```
 import numpy as np
 H1 = np.random.randn(50, 50) + 10
 p = 0.5
 U1 = np.random.rand(*H1.shape) < p
```

In particular, what is the `*` doing to `H1.shape` inside the `np.random.rand` function?

Comment: Not numpy. Python.

Comment: Summary of the above: It expands the shape tuple as if each element in it were separate arg passed to the function.

Comment: Ah - thanks @MadPhysicist. That's perfect. I couldn't find the answer because it's associated with python and not numpy.

Comment: For the future, when reading any weird notation in Python, remember that libraries just provide packages, modules, functions and constants. Pretty much all symbol characters are part of the language itself.

Comment: If the linked posts were helpful, remember to upvote them.